# Laravel - How to Display Submit Edit and Delete based on is_approved

Tags: laravel

I have this code in my Laravel-5.8

```
public function index()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->get();

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index')->with('goals', $goals);
}
```

view

```html
   <td>
      @if ($goal->is_approved == 3)
            <span class="badge bg-success" >Approved</span>
      @elseif ($goal->is_approved == 2)
              <span class="badge bg-danger">Not Approved</span>
      @elseif ($goal->is_approved == 1)
           <span class="badge bg-info">Awaiting Approval</span>                                  
      @else
           <span class="badge bg-black">Draft</span>                                    
       @endif
  </td>
      <td>                               
          @can('appraisal_goal_show')
             <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.show', $goal->id) }}">
                  {{ trans('global.view') }}
             </a> 
          @endcan
          @can('appraisal_goal_edit')
              <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.edit', ['id'=>$goal->id]) }}">
                   {{ trans('global.edit') }}
              </a>
           @endcan
           @can('appraisal_goal_delete')
               <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="deleteTag({{ $goal->id }})">
                      Delete
               </button>
            <form id="delete-form-{{ $goal->id }}" action="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.destroy',$goal->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                   @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
              </form>
             @endcan   
       </td>

        <div class="col-12">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href ="{{ route('post.publish.all')}}" class="btn btn-primary float-left"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Submit</a>                         
        </div>
```

I want to apply this conditions.

1. Edit should only be visible when is_approved = 1 or 2 or 3
2. Delete should only be visible when is_approved = 0 or 2
3. Submit button should only be visible when is_approved = 1 or 2

How do I achieve these?

Thanks

Comment: where do you have is_approved field?

Comment: The is approved is in the AppraisalGoal, that is appraisal_goals. $goals = AppraisalGoal.   I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may nest each of your buttons inside an `@if` and check `is_approved` value with `in_array` function:

```
@if(in_array($goal->is_approved, [1, 2, 3]))
    @can('appraisal_goal_edit')
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.edit', ['id'=>$goal->id]) }}">
            {{ trans('global.edit') }}
        </a>
    @endcan
@endif
```

You may do the same for delete and submit buttons and just change the 2nd argument of `in_array`.